# var gets [] outside for loop nodejs

Tags: node.js

I have data inside 3 arrays and i need to join everything in one but i need to create a new array where I have a timestamp and x1,x2,x3 where x1,x2,x3 are each value of each array.

Like live=1, repeated=2, passerBy=3 I will have array=[timestamp, 1, 2, 3]

I have my arrays live, repeated and passerBy with values.

I dont understand why array inst being fullfilled with values... is always print []

```
var live=[];
var repeated=[];
var passerBy=[];
var data=[];
live=[["2017-07-22T14:39:21.000Z","836"],["2017-07-22T14:44:21.000Z","207"],["2017-07-22T14:49:21.000Z","2006"],["2017-07-22T14:54:21.000Z","402"],["2017-07-22T14:59:22.000Z","198"],["2017-07-22T15:04:22.000Z","597"],["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","180"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","138"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","293"]];
repeated=[["2017-07-22T14:39:21.000Z","18"],["2017-07-22T14:44:21.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T14:49:21.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T14:54:21.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T14:59:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:04:22.000Z","9"],["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","2"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","1"]];
passerBy=[["2017-07-22T14:39:21.000Z","128"],["2017-07-22T14:44:21.000Z","518"],["2017-07-22T14:49:21.000Z","1258"],["2017-07-22T14:54:21.000Z","334"],["2017-07-22T14:59:22.000Z","128"],["2017-07-22T15:04:22.000Z","211"],["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","104"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","60"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","380"]];

    for(var l=0; l<live.length; l++){
        for(var r=0; r<repeated.length; r++){
            if(live[l][0] == repeated[r][0]){
                var aux = [];
                aux.push(live[l][0]);
                aux.push(live[l][1]);
                aux.push(repeated[r][1]);
                data.push(aux);
            }
        }
        console.log("data for 1 ",data);
    }

    console.log('array for 2', data);

    for(var p=0; p<passerBy.length;p++){
        for(var a=0; a<data.length; a++){
            if(passerBy[p][0] == data[a][0]){
                data[a].push(passerBy[p][1]);
            }
        }
    }

    console.log('array for 3', data);

    for(var a=0; a<data.length;a++){
        //array[a][0] = Date(array[a][0]).toString());

        data[a][0]=new Date(Date.parse(data[a][0]));
    }

    console.log('array for 4', data);
```

My logs:

```
2|wscontro | [2017-07-22 17:11:25.899] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/logs LogsController f051b333-8f1f-4e65-9acc-e76470a87f47 getAllProbingRows live [["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","180"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","138"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","293"],["2017-07-22T15:31:22.000Z","1145"],["2017-07-22T15:36:22.000Z","205"],["2017-07-22T15:42:22.000Z","306"],["2017-07-22T15:47:23.000Z","52"],["2017-07-22T15:52:23.000Z","141"],["2017-07-22T15:57:23.000Z","694"]]
2|wscontro | [2017-07-22 17:11:25.899] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/logs LogsController f051b333-8f1f-4e65-9acc-e76470a87f47 getAllProbingRows repeated [["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","2"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:31:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:36:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:42:22.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:47:23.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:52:23.000Z","1"],["2017-07-22T15:57:23.000Z","1"]]
2|wscontro | [2017-07-22 17:11:25.900] - debug: /opt/wscontroller/wscontroller-api/routes/logs LogsController f051b333-8f1f-4e65-9acc-e76470a87f47 getAllProbingRows passerBy [["2017-07-22T15:16:22.000Z","104"],["2017-07-22T15:21:22.000Z","60"],["2017-07-22T15:26:22.000Z","380"],["2017-07-22T15:31:22.000Z","230"],["2017-07-22T15:36:22.000Z","117"],["2017-07-22T15:42:22.000Z","370"],["2017-07-22T15:47:23.000Z","145"],["2017-07-22T15:52:23.000Z","185"],["2017-07-22T15:57:23.000Z","127"]]

2|wscontro | array for 1  []
2|wscontro | array for 2  []
2|wscontro | array for 3  []
2|wscontro | array for 4  []
```

Comment: I have run your code and it worked fine.

Comment: It works using (up-to-date) FF or node.js.

Comment: But im working in my project with express and it's not working...